# Send While Loop To Next Row If No Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Because we can't set table-cell's max-height so I am using this loop to limit row height (equal to cell), by increasing the table width until all rows height < height I set in loop.

```
var i = 0,
    row, table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
    j = table.offsetWidth;
while (row = table.rows[i++]) {
    while (row.offsetHeight > 200 && j < 3000) {
        j += 250;
        table.style.width = j + 'px';
    }
}
```

But there is a problem in this script, if for some reason a specific row height can't be less than 400px, which is greater than max-height I set for rows in script, the table becomes unnecessary 3000px wide because of the condition in loop.

Is there any way to send loop to next row if a row height is same before and after table width increment by loop. I tried web searching but nothing found to handle this, if anyone here knows about this please help me

Example (no problem when no `<br/>` tag): http://jsfiddle.net/jm5cpqr4/5/

Example (problem when `<br/>` usage limiting least possible height of cell): http://jsfiddle.net/jm5cpqr4/6/

Comment: I don't exactly understand you, but maybe you are looking for this? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: ok, but is there anything unclear i wrote?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jm5cpqr4/2/ ? can you edit it to recreate the issue

Comment: @Arun ok i am editing it

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly, but what is it that you have in these table cells? That makes a difference because you may need also set line-height.

Comment: @Joshua just simple text with `<br/>` in some places.

Comment: Try setting line height then. I've seen similar issues before. I don't know if that is the answer, but I do recommend that it is worth a try.

Comment: @Joshua thanks for comment, you mean css line height?

Comment: Yes, CSS line-height.

Comment: how can line-height solve this problem ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

script47 correctly indicated a break statement is used in the resolution.

Readers may need to reduce the offset value tested in the "failing" case on jsfiddle to reproduce the problem in their browser - it did't immediately fail for me

A solution example:

```
function loaded()
{   var i = 0,  row, table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
    j = table.offsetWidth;
    var testHeight = 100;

    while (row = table.rows[i++])
    {   var h0 = row.offsetHeight;
            while (row.offsetHeight > testHeight && j < 3000)
        {   j += testHeight;
            table.style.width = j + 'px';
            if(row.offsetHeight==h0)
            {    table.style.width = j-testHeight + 'px'
                 break;
            }
        }
   }
}
loaded();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but your code is not working on 2nd row see: http://jsfiddle.net/5cubnojq/ and 2nd row height go above 200px as there is no table width.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't copy and paste the final result.. I've updated the example above, made "testHieight" a variable and tested it on that last fiddle  with a test height of 100. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, your code is working but when i tried lowering increment to get accurate results it's not working because it is possible for rows to not change the height in each small width increment if we set. So i tried to fix it with if and else and i think it is working but can you check it just last time and tell me can i use it because i think it's bad for performance...thanks

Comment: I can see what you are doing. To improve efficiency 1. Take              "   var jnow = table.offsetWidth - increm

Comment: sorry i didn't understand, because is my first time i am editing a loop

Comment: I can see what you are doing. To improve efficiency suggest taking "table.style.width = maxwidth + 'px';" out of the inner loop and save in a variable, say hMinimum under h0 in the outer loop. Possibilities also include use a binary search algorithm to find the table width or to start with a large increment and backtrack one step and try smaller increments as required.   (my edit time expired!)